# MAMP 500 Error for phpLiteAdmin

Tags: mamp

After a fresh install I'm only getting phpLiteAdmin as a database option but when I navigate to that page it gives me a 500 error:

http://localhost:8888/phpLiteAdmin/phpliteadmin.php

Everything is green, Apache, MySQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem, but I trying changing the php version 7.1.1 to 7.0.15 and phpmyadmin and phplite working again.